# selenium chrome options (running in backgroud)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get some information from a website and Chrome should run in the background to fulfill that task. Down there you can see my code. It works so far and I get the desired output, but when I add the `chrome_options` so that Chrome is hidden I don't get the output anymore.

What's the problem and how can I fix this?

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_stockname(wkn):

PATH = r"***placeholder***chromedriver.exe"
url = "***placeholder***"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)
search_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('input-field__text-input')
search_box.send_keys(wkn)
search_box.submit()
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[13]/div[2]/div[1]/h2").text
name = name[13:]
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like that, but with replacing your url:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://google.com"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)
search_box = browser.find_element_by_class_name('input-field__text-input')
search_box.send_keys(wkn)
search_box.submit()
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//h2[@class='box-headline'])[2]").get_attribute('innerText')
name = name[13:]
print(name)
```

By the way, can you show DOM code snipped to make element more unique with such external relation or even URL and element what info you want to get out?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the code still does not work with the changes.
To be honest I didn't got what you want to tell me with your comment below the code. I'm not to familiar with the topic in general. What I want to get from the website is a string.

Comment: URL is https://www.finanzen.net and I want to get the titel of a stock (I took it from the realtimeBox on the right).

Comment: When you search for any stock like Daimler: https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/daimler-aktie

It is the box where REALTIMEKURS DAIMLER AG stands on the right.

Comment: @doctor i've update the code snipped, try to use print(name.get_attribute('innerText'))